# how to convert string time to nanosecond time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string variable looks like this `09:30:00.031883382`. I want to convert it to time format. I tried

`pd.to_datetime(pd.time, unit ='ns').dt.time`

and

`pd.to_datetime(pd.time, format ="%H:%M:%S.%f").dt.time`.

Both of them rounded the time to `09:30:00.031883`. Can anyone teach me how to covert this string to time format but keep the time accurate at nanosecond level (keep all 9 digits after second) please.

Comment: Do you want to access the nanoseconds? I believe the second way is correct, what happens if you `.dt.nanosecond`?

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo, when I try to replicate, I get 0. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give a time string with no date to `pd.to_datetime()`, as in `'09:30:00.031883382'`, pandas by default inserts the current date into the resulting `Timestamp` object. (`Timestamp` objects always have both a date and a time.) For some reason, this default behaviour seems to discard nanoseconds, whereas explicitly providing a date (such as the current date) preserves nanoseconds in the resulting `Timestamp`:

```
In [1]: d1 = pd.to_datetime('09:30:00.031883382')

In [2]: d1
Out[2]: Timestamp('2019-02-09 09:30:00.031883')

In [3]: d1.nanosecond
Out[3]: 0


In [4]: d2 = pd.to_datetime('2019-02-09 09:30:00.031883382')

In [5]: d2
Out[5]: Timestamp('2019-02-09 09:30:00.031883382')

In [6]: d2.nanosecond
Out[6]: 382
```

So one solution is to specify a valid date together with the nanosecond-resolution time.

Another solution is to use `pd.to_timedelta` instead of `pd.to_datetime`:

```
In [7]: d3 = pd.to_timedelta('09:30:00.031883382')

In [8]: d3
Out[8]: Timedelta('0 days 09:30:00.031883')

In [9]: d3.nanoseconds   # timedelta uses "nanosecondS" but timestamp uses "nanosecond"
Out[9]: 382
```